# Как выровнять по вертикали контент в шапке?

Tags: css

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 1024px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

header {
  background: #F05C5C;
  color: white;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

nav {
  float: right;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 20px;
}

nav li:hover {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="motion">
        <p><img src="image/logo.png" class="logo"> Motion
        <br> A Single Page Template</p>
      </div>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

1. С помощью `flex`:

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 1024px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

header {
  background: #F05C5C;
  color: white;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

nav {
  float: right;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 20px;
}

nav li:hover {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="motion">
      <p><img src="image/logo.png" class="logo"> Motion
      <br> A Single Page Template</p>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

2. Пример с `table-cell`:

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 1024px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

header {
  background: #F05C5C;
  color: white;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.motion,
nav {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

nav {
  text-align: right;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 20px;
}

nav li:hover {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="motion">
      <p><img src="image/logo.png" class="logo"> Motion
      <br> A Single Page Template</p>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

3. Пример с `float` + отступы:

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 1024px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

header {
  background: #F05C5C;
  color: white;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.motion {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

nav {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 1.25rem 0;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 20px;
}

nav li:hover {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="motion">
      <p><img src="image/logo.png" class="logo"> Motion
      <br> A Single Page Template</p>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
   body {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 1024px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

header {
  background: #F05C5C;
  color: white;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

nav ul li {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 20px;
}

nav li:hover {
  background: black;
}

.motion {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
  <header>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="motion">
        <p><img src="image/logo.png" class="logo"> Motion
        <br> A Single Page Template</p>
      </div>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
```

Никогда не используй в коде тег

Answer (score 0):

Приветствую вас! Может быть так?

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  background: #F05C5C;
  color: white;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 1024px;
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.motion {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

nav {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 20px;
}

nav li:hover {
  background: black;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 0 5px;
  line-height: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="motion">
        <img src="image/logo.png" class="logo"> Motion<br> A Single Page Template
      </div>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>


</body>

</html>
```